# Reformatting the error messages coming from dataflow in Azure Data Factory V2

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory

I am catching error message as the come from dataflow in my for each activity. My stored procedure uses this expression to capture it, `@activity('Data flow1').error.Message`  and it shows up like this,

```
Operation on target ForEach1 failed: Activity failed because an inner activity failed; Inner activity name: Copy data1, Error: ErrorCode=UserErrorInvalidColumnName,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The column Card PI is not found in target side,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'
```

I would like to only get the "Message=The column Card PI is not found in target side"  how would i accomplish this in azure? i could try to parse and split string in SQL but some messages dont have a "Message=" like the following example

```
{"StatusCode":"DFExecutorUserError","Message":"Job failed due to reason: at Source 'source1': org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileAlreadyExistsException: GET https://saautouploaddev.dfs.core.windows.net/uploads?resource=filesystem&maxResults=5000&directory=Verified_Files/CSV&timeout=90&recursive=false\nStatusCode=409\nStatusDescription=This endpoint does not support BlobStorageEvents or SoftDelete. Please disable these account features if you would like to use this endpoint.\nErrorCode=EndpointUnsupportedAccountFeatures\nErrorMessage=This endpoint does not support BlobStorageEvents or SoftDelete. Please disable these account features if you would like to use this endpoint.\nRequestId:424fcdc3-b01f-0046-5f7e-b09ca7000000\nTime:2021-09-23T13:26:19.5585418Z","Details":"org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileAlreadyExistsException: GET https://saautouploaddev.dfs.core.windows.net/uploads?resource=filesystem&maxResults=5000&directory=Verified_Files/CSV&timeout=90&recursive=false\nStatusCode=409\nStatusDescription=This endpoint does not support BlobStorageEvents or SoftDelete. Please disable these account features if you would like to use this endpoint.\nErrorCode=EndpointUnsupportedAccountFeatures\nErrorMessage=This endpoint does not support BlobStorageEvents or SoftDelete. Please disable these account features if you would like to use this endpoint.\nRequestId:424fcdc3-b01f-0046-5f7e-b09ca7000000\nTime:2021-09-23T13:26:19.5585418Z\n\tat shaded.databricks.v20180920_b33d810.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.checkException(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:910)\n\tat shaded.databricks.v20180920_b33d810.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.listStatus(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:342)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.listStatus(Globber.java:69)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.glob(Globb"}
```

Comment: I suggest that you beware of this. When you add unneeded logic to error logging, you run the risk of your error logging failing, then your error is lost and your activity can fail, not because of an actual failure, but because your error log failed. Particularly with string parsing as it can be susceptible to things like -1 index errors. I suggest you clean it up in a subsequent view instead

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, I agree with you on that, that is why I was wondering if azure had a child method in its Message class that I can call to get certain parts of an error message. I.E. @activity('data flow 1').error.Message.whateverMaybeHereToCall, would be cleaner than string manipulation.

Comment: There is no class, it's just JSON. You could try using some JSON shredding functions that you get out of the box with ADF but be prepared for some very large unmaintainable inline expressions. I've found error capturing very inconsistent. You need to go to different parts of the JSON result to capture the error depending on what the activity type is, and some activities don't appear to output errors

Comment: Actually... since the result is a string and not JSON, you can't use JSON shredding. I really do suggest you save everything into your logging table and do it in SQL. YOu don't want your activity failing because your logging logic had a indxex error

Comment: true, i believe i will go that route. thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

Wrangled with this same issue for an entire day. Here is my solution: @replace(json(activity('Data Flow').error.Message).Message,'"','')

Converting the error message to json, referencing the Message portion of the result, and removing double quotes (") results in a properly formatted string.